# how to loop a INNER JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

Some users on this forum helped me creating this inner join

```
SELECT a.*, p.* FROM artist a INNER JOIN pics p on p.id_artist = a.id
```

to query these tables

```
      artist                          pics
-------------------       ---------------------------------------
| id | name | age |       | id_artist | picUrl | picDescription |
-------------------       ---------------------------------------
   |                          /\
   ----------------------------
```

Now what i get when i loop the resultSet is:

```
1    michael jackson    50    img/435432.jpg    concert
1    michael jackson    50    img/213234.jpg    family
1    michael jackson    50    img/123163.jpg    concert
```

What id like to "get" is:

```
1    michael jackson    50    img/435432.jpg    concert
                              img/213234.jpg    family
                              img/123163.jpg    concert
```

but i can't understand how loop it.

I have to put the outcome of the query in many object called Artist. These are it's field

```
int id;
String name;
int age;
Pic pics [];
```

this is the object Pic

```
int idArtist;
String Url;
String Description
```

So what i should do is something like:

```
while(resulset.next()){
   Artist artist = new Artist();
   artist.setId(resulset.getInt("a.id"));
   ........
   Pic pic = new Pic();
   pic.setIdArtist(resulset.getInt("a.id"));
   pic.setUrl(resulset.getInt("p.picUrl"));
   .....
   artist.setPic(pic );
}
```

But this is not correct, because this way i get an Artist object for every pic that is in the db. What i want is just one Artist object and many Pic objects  inside the artist object.

Comment: not clear what you want??? what loop??

Comment: You perhaps should keep track of the last printed line and if it's the same as the current, skip it. What is your code so far?

Comment: This has nothing to do with how you loop it, but how you print it.  How are you printing it now?

Comment: as @ScottHunter said, it all depends on how you print stuff. if you using java to print, then show some codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you get an idea/direction to proceed further with below code.

```
String myCurrentID = "";
String strPreviousID = "";

while (moreRecordsAvailable)
{
    myCurrentID = resulset.getString("ID");
    if (!myCurrentID.equals(strPreviousID ))
    {
        // If the previous and current are different, then add both artist and picture objects
         strPreviousID =        myCurrentID ;
         Artist artist = new Artist();
         artist.setId(resulset.getString("a.id"));
         ........
         Pic pic = new Pic();
         pic.setIdArtist(resulset.getString("a.id"));
         pic.setUrl(resulset.getInt("p.picUrl"));
         .....
        artist.setPic(pic );
    }
    else
    {
        // If previous and current is same, then add only pictures object. Need not add artist object here.
        Pic pic = new Pic();
        pic.setIdArtist(resulset.getString("a.id"));
        pic.setUrl(resulset.getInt("p.picUrl"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it using `JSP` and `html`(table) you can loop through `resultset` and  `html` attribute like `colspan` and `rowspan` will help you to generate desired output in `html` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with just sql, I think you can do that with just writting a pl/sql procedure. First of all it will hold your query result in an array and then you can use it for print them freely in format which you want.

```
DECLARE
cursor cursor1 
SELECT a.*, p.* FROM artist a INNER JOIN pics p on p.id_artist = a.id;
artist_rec  cursor1%rowtype;  --structure of one row
Type artist_array IS VARRAY(25) OF cursor1%rowtype -- array structure for holding returned select query
artist_arr artist_array; -- our array variable
i   NUMBER:=1;
BEGIN
    artist_arr  := artist_array; -- initialize array
    Open cursor1;
LOOP
    FETCH cursor1 into artist_rec  
    artist_arr .EXTEND(1); -- add another element to array with extend it
    artist_arr  (i) := artist_rec ; -- assign fetched row to array
    i := i + 1;  -- increment element count
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor1;
FOR j IN artist_arr.FIRST.. artist_arr.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT_PUTLINE('') -- You can loop in result now, left is about output formats
                            -- and also you must hold a list of printed artist to avoid
                            -- not to write again


END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a `List<Artist>` and override `Artist#equals` and `Artist#hashCode` to delegate only to Artist name. Then use `List#contains` to see if you need to add a new one or take the existing one. Finally make `pics` a `List<Pic>` as well so you can dynamically add `Pic`s to your `Artist`. It's about code design choices, not about the SQL output.